# Create javascript object using dotted string

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have some javascript object eg var person = {};

and I am given a string that represents a dotted traversal into that object eg "Address.Suburb"

and another string that represents the value to be set. eg "Your Town"

What is a general function to enable this to be set.  The properties may or may not exist prior to invocation, the function will need 
to create the properties if necessary.

```
function MySetter(object, stringTraversal, valueToSet) {
    ....
}
```

such that

```
var person = {};

MySetter(person, "Address.Suburb", "CrazyTown")

alert(person.Address.Suburb); // alerts CrazyTown
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function setObjPath(obj,path,value){
  var parts = path.split('.'), part;

  function error(txt){
      throw new TypeError(txt);
  }

  while (part = parts.shift()){
    if (parts.length){
        obj = part in obj && obj[part] instanceof Object 
              ? obj[part] 
              : part in obj 
                ? error('key ['+part+'] exists but is not an object') 
                : (obj[part] = {}, obj[part]);
    } else {
       obj[part] = value;
    }
  }
}
// usage examples
var person = {name: {prename: {first:'Pete',full:'Pete Michael'}}};

setObjPath(person, 'name.surname.first','Johansen');
alert(person.name.prename.first +' '+person.name.surname.first);
 //=> Pete Johansen

setObjPath(person, 'name.prename.first','George');
alert(person.name.prename.first+' '+person.name.surname.first);
 //=> George Johansen

setObjPath(person, 'name.prename.first.isset',true);
 //=> throws TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the poor naming

```
function MySetter(obj, path, value){
      var paths = path.split(".");
      var path;
      var ans;
      for(var i in paths) {
                obj = obj[paths[i]];
      };
      return ans;
}
```

Edit :: I misunderstood the question I think. This returns the value in the string path, and you want to set it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function MySetter(object, string, value) {
    if (typeof string === 'string') {
        string = string.split('.');
    }

    if (typeof object[string[0]] === 'object')
        return MySetter(object[string[0]], string.slice(1), value);
    else
        return object[string[0]];
}
```

That should do the trick!

EDIT: Yeah, I misunderstood it, too…

```
function MySetter(object, string, value) {
    if (typeof string === 'string') {
        string = string.split('.');
    }

    if (string.length === 2) {
        object[string[1]] = value;
    } else {
        return MySetter(object[string[0]], string.slice(1), value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try writing your own parser.

```
function MySetter(object, stringTraversal, valueToSet) {
    var prop = stringTraversal.split('.'),
        len = prop.length,
        obj = object,
        attr = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         attr = prop[i];
         if (i == len - 1) {
             obj[attr] = valueToSet;
             return;
         }
         if (!obj[attr] && i < len - 1) {
             obj[attr] = {};
         }
         obj = obj[attr];
    }
}
```

Something like this (no time to test it).

Answer (score 0):

```
function MySetter(object, stringTraversal, valueToSet) {
    var pieces = stringTraversal.split('.');

    for(var i in pieces) {
        var val = {};
        if(i == pieces.length-1) {
            val = valueToSet;
        }
        object[pieces[i]] = val;
        object = object[pieces[i]];
    }
}

var person = {};

MySetter(person, "Address.Suburb", "CrazyTown")

alert(person.Address.Suburb); // alerts CrazyTown
```